# How best to use R to reshape dataframe from long to wide and combine values

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a dataframe of about 2000 rows and 3 columns. In essence, I want to reshape this dataframe to be wider than longer. This is an example of my current data:

| ID | Procedure | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D55 | Sedation | 01/01/2001 |
| D55 | Excision | 01/01/2001 |
| D55 | Biopsy | 01/01/2001 |
| A66 | Sedation | 02/02/2001 |
| A66 | Excision | 02/02/2001 |
| T44 | Sedation | 03/03/2001 |
| T44 | Biopsy | 03/03/2001 |
| T44 | Sedation | 04/04/2001 |
| T44 | Excision | 04/04/2001 |
| G88 | Sedation | 05/05/2001 |
| G88 | Biopsy | 05/05/2001 |
| G88 | Sedation | 06/06/2001 |
| G88 | Excision | 06/06/2001 |
| G88 | Sedation | 07/07/2001 |
| G88 | Re-excision | 07/07/2001 |

I want the each row to be one line for the ID, so I'd want to create something like this:

| ID | Date 1 | Procedure(s) | Date 2 | Procedure(s) | Date 3 | Procedure(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D55 | 01/01/2001 | Sedation, Excision, Biopsy |  |  |  |  |
| A66 | 02/02/2001 | Sedation, Excision |  |  |  |  |
| T44 | 03/03/2001 | Sedation, Biopsy | 04/04/2001 | Sedation, Excision |  |  |
| G88 | 05/05/2001 | Sedation, Biopsy | 06/06/2001 | Sedation, Excision | 07/07/2001 | Sedation, Re-excision |

The majority of IDs all have the same date, but different procedures documented. There are a handful that came in for further procedures on subsequent dates. I can't see any that came in for more than 3 different dates, but a way to count the dates documented per ID would be useful.

I've tried using cast and dcast so far, but I'm not really getting anywhere. I'm very new to R, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Date) %>%
  summarize(Procedure = paste0(Procedure, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  mutate(col = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = c(Date, Procedure))
```

This currently requires some reordering afterwards, which could be done like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400134/6851825

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  ID    Date_1 Date_2 Date_3 Procedure_1                Procedure_2        Procedure_3          
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>                      <chr>              <chr>                
1 A66   2/2/01 NA     NA     Sedation, Excision         NA                 NA                   
2 D55   1/1/01 NA     NA     Sedation, Excision, Biopsy NA                 NA                   
3 G88   5/5/01 6/6/01 7/7/01 Sedation, Biopsy           Sedation, Excision Sedation, Re-excision
4 T44   3/3/01 4/4/01 NA     Sedation, Biopsy           Sedation, Excision NA
```